# What are meaning of these (P(x;y), P(x;y,z),P(x,y;z))?

Tags: probability, multivalued-functions

I was reading a machine learning book that it uses probabilities like these:

```
P(x;y), P(x;y,z),P(x,y;z)
```

I couldn't find what they are and how can I read and understand them?

A part of the context I saw one of these probabilities on it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf0X7.png)

Comment: Guess: P(x;y) - probability of x on condition y.  P(x;y,z) - probability of x on condition y and z.  P(x,y;z) - probability of x and y on condition z.  Usual notation uses | instead of ;.

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: No it's not conditional. cause the book uses `|` for conditional probability.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: For example in the book, there is a probability like this `P(x|y;theta)` and it call it `probability of x given y parameterized by theta`.

Comment: @leonbloy: I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that different distributions have different parameters. Say you have $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Instead of denoting the distribution as $f_X(x)$ (or $p_X(x)$ for discrete random variables), the book uses $f_X(x;\mu,\sigma)$ (or $f(x;\mu,\sigma)$; simply omitting the subscript). The variables *before* the semicolon denote the realization of the random variable(s) and ones right *after* denote the parameters that define such distribution.

**EDIT**

Regrading your inquiry about the parameters, again let us look at the Gaussian distribution. It is *characterized* by two parameters, namely: mean (denoted $\mu$)  and variance (denoted $\sigma^2$). These parameters alter the shape of the distribution. In particular, the mean defines where the curve is centered at while the variance define the spread or how much the realizations vary around the mean. I got the figure below from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) to help you better understand what is it that I'm describing. I hope this clears out your confusion.

[image]

Comment: +1 And notice that it's highly unusual (and in bad mathematical taste) to use letters like $y,z$ for parameters associated to a variable $x$, as the OP did - it makes you think that all are random variables. Normally a different kind of letter is used for parameters than for random variables. That's why we could not guess the meaning before seeing the original.

Comment: Thank you Lod. But I have a question, why does it use parameters in probability? I mean what is the difference between `P(y) and P(Y;etha)` in above example?

Comment: @Hasani There is no difference if you are talking about the same distribution. In other words, $p(y)$ is $p(y;\theta)$ if the distribution of $Y$ is characterized by $\theta$. Please see my edit for more details.